# Motivation for defining space-like vector

Tags: differential-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry

Maybe an elementary question:

What is the motivation for defining the vector $X=0$ to be space-like?

Comment: what do you mean mathematically by "space-like"?

Comment: I assume you are speaking about Special Relativity?  But of course such terminology is specific to the application, not general.  In any case, my understanding was that for four vectors you simply define the first component to be timelike and the rest of them spacelike, so the terms refer to components not vectors.  But I may have the vocabulary wrong.

Comment: @Immanuel my references call vectors having zero length (among which it is $0$) light vectors, while they call space-like vectors those whose squared lenght is negative. Where did you find what you say?

Comment: I'm familiar with special relativity and its terminology. I think this is a terminology in mathematics literature, e.g. semi-Riemannian geometry (see for instance the first page of [Lorentzian Manifolds](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi7j9HW7sfVAhUSZlAKHbDzBg8QFghSMAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.springer.com%2Fcda%2Fcontent%2Fdocument%2Fcda_downloaddocument%2F9783642027796-c1.pdf%3FSGWID%3D0-0-45-800045-p173910618&usg=AFQjCNEixG7JW6ve9wwiIzsJ7IkGFl7KWg)). I think there must be a reason why people define $X=0$ to be space-like.

Answer (score 0):

A spacelike subspace of a Lorentz vector space is one for which the restricted Lorentz scalar product is positive-definite. The restriction of the Lorentz scalar product to the zero subspace is technically positive-definite, because you cannot find a non-zero vector there (!) whose scalar square is non-positive.